# Material UI and React: prevent popup of Autocomplete to close when focusing on a child input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an autocomplete popup and when an item inside is clicked, a `Popper` shows and it has an input field. I want to edit the selected value like the image but when I focus on the input field by adding `autoFocus` to the `InputBase`, it closes the popup. Or when I simply click the input field, it doesn't focus.

[image]

I assume when the autocomplete's focus is off, the popup will close so I can't edit the input field in the `Popper` but is there a way around this to work?

This is my autocomplete's setting.

```
  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputLabelProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: "use-autocomplete-demo",
    options: countries,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.label,
    disableCloseOnSelect: true
  });
```

And the whole module:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextField, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Autocomplete, useAutocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
import Item from "./Item";

const App = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const countries = [
    { code: "US", label: "USA", phone: "1" },
    { code: "HU", label: "Hungary ", phone: "2" },
    { code: "IT", label: "Italy ", phone: "3" }
  ];

  const openMultipleOptionSearch = (event) => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputLabelProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: "use-autocomplete-demo",
    options: countries,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.label,
    disableCloseOnSelect: true
  });

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      <Paper>
        {groupedOptions.length > 0 &&
          groupedOptions.map((option, index) => (
            <Item key={index} text={option.label} onClose={() => {}} />
          ))}
        {groupedOptions.length === 0 && <p>No match.</p>}
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can control mine with onClose function like this:

```
     <Autocomplete
        disabled={disabled}
        id={name}
        name={name}
        sx={{width: "100%"}}
        open={open}
        onOpen={() => {
            setOpen(true);
        }}
        onClose={() => {
            // setOpen(false);
        }}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        value={value}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option?.[id] === value?.[id]}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.[label]}
        options={options}
        onChange={(e, value) => onChange(value)}
        loading={loadingApi}
        noOptionsText={noOption}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
                name={name}
                required={required}
                variant="standard"
                {...params}
                label={showName}
                onChange={(e) => setFilters(e.target.value)}
                InputProps={{
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    onblur:() => {},
                    endAdornment: (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            {loadingApi ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20}/> : null}
                            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        )}
    />
```

Comment: Can you do the same with useAutocomplete?

Comment: can you see this [link](https://www.unpkg.com/browse/@material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.40/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.d.ts)

you may found the answer with trying these props.